# Why gulp-eslint doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, gulp, frontend, lint

I have this task in my gulpfile:

```
gulp.task('js', function () {
return gulp.src('js/main.js')
    .pipe(eslint({

    }))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});
```

But when I run it , console is clear.

```
D:\workflow\training\js_learn\task_1>gulp js                                                  
[19:40:51] Using gulpfile D:\workflow\training\js_learn\task_1\gulpfile.js                    
[19:40:51] Starting 'js'...                                                                   
[19:40:51] Finished 'js' after 302 ms
```

But I know, that there are errors in my JS

Comment: Did you require eslint in your task file?

Comment: eslint = require('gulp-eslint');?
yes, i required it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the task I use. It works well. Perhaps your issue is due to the fact that you are passing an empty options object to `eslint()`?

```
var eslint = require('gulp-eslint');

return gulp
    .src(config.path.js)
    .pipe(eslint())
    .pipe(eslint.format());
```

Comment: Oh, now it works, but how can I specify my own settings?Or can you share your settings?

Comment: I use a `.eslintrc` file. eslint will use this file automatically if it is present. More info and sample file: [.eslintrc docs](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring.html#specifying-language-options). Here's an example of a file in use: [.eslintrc working example](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/.eslintrc)

Comment: perhaps it's good to explain why you have to add the eslint.format

Comment: @albertjan `eslint.format()` outputs the lint results to the console. https://github.com/adametry/gulp-eslint#usage

Answer (score 4):

By default `eslint` doesn't enforce any rules.  For a quick solution, try creating a .eslintrc file using `eslint` and then customize it as needed.

1. `npm install -g eslint` // you may need to `sudo` for global install, but you should fix that
2. `eslint --init` // answer the questions

then edit your `.eslintrc` file for whatever rules you need (see http://eslint.org/docs/rules/)

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple of issues with just using eslint like that on **all of the files**.. But mainly it is just to SLOW!

The solution in my opinion?

Lint only the **staged git files** that you've currently worked on.

I saw some solutions of doing that, but all of them had 1 problem: they were still too slow!

Most of them tried to use git status for each file to see if we should lint it or not.. so the problem was still that we did some operations on files that we didn't worked on..

So I tried to do just that in our project, here is the example of what I did:
[gulp-eslint-precommit](https://github.com/kazazor/gulp-eslint-precommit).

It is very fast since it is doing only 1 git status operation, and then lints only the needed files.

It also uses [Google's js style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javascriptguide.xml) so no need to define your own rules.. Just use what Google uses..

I hope this helps :-)

Comment: You can also use something like gulp-cached that will only lint the files you have changed.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but gulp-cache requires the process to keep on running in the background in order to work.. Right? If that is the case then it is not good here, since mostly the need is on pre-commit hook so the process will die and gulp-cache won't work

Comment: Yes, I guess. You would use it on a watch so you could be actively linting the files that you are working on as opposed to the defined paths.